# group by toggling Rows and difference in rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, gaps-and-islands

I have data as follows:

```
Date time            Switch Water level
2015/08/07 09:00:00  1      7
2015/08/07 09:05:00  1      7
2015/08/07 09:10:00  1      6
2015/08/07 09:15:00  1      5
2015/08/07 09:20:00  1      5
2015/08/07 12:00:00  0      5
2015/08/07 15:00:00  0      5
2015/08/07 18:00:00  1      5
2015/08/07 18:05:00  1      4
2015/08/07 18:10:00  1      3
2015/08/07 18:15:00  1      2
2015/08/07 21:00:00  0      2
2015/08/08 00:00:00  0      2
```

I want to group data by different sets of 1 and 0 in 'switch' column 
also I want to find difference of water level within group. the result should be

```
switch  decrease in water level
1        2
0        0
1        3
0        0
```

My 1st Priority is to group by Switch column. 
 2nd priority is to find the difference. If it is not possible than ignore the 2nd priority but please help me way to group by different sets of 1 and 0 in switch column.  
It would be awsome if some could help me do this.

```
session Start Time           End Time              decrease_in_level
1       2015/08/07 09:00:00  2015/08/07 09:20:00   2
2       2015/08/07 18:00:00  2015/08/07 18:15:00   3
```

Comment: do water level always go in increments of 1 in the same direction, or can they have greater intervals as well as going +/- in the same group?

Comment: The problem here is you're assuming order of data in the system which can't be guaranteed on retrieval.  Is there a datetime, or sequence ID associated to these two columns as well to ensure proper ordering?

Comment: If there is no column that can be used to differentiate the first group of 1's from the second group of 1's, then what you want is not possible.

Comment: Well, and what would you like to see if in switch 1 you get the following data: 5 , 6 , 7, 5. Also do you have an Id on the table? If so please refres your question,

Comment: Tanner: Water level always decrease in same directions with difference of level 0 or 1

Comment: XQbert: Yes there is Datetime column to ensure the ordering

Comment: PeterRing: Switch column is a Bit type column it it always have 0 or 1 (it represents switch on or of)

Comment: when the switch is power ON the motor turns ON and water start decreasing. (table have ID, MotorID, Datetime, Switch [On/off], Water Level% columns.

I also need difference of Datetime column to calculate for what duration motor keeps running and how much water it consumed in every motor session. consecutive 1 represents one motor session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-island problem and one way to solve it is to identify the islands of interest using some row_number trickery and once that's done we can apply aggregate functions (min and max) to get the first and last values in each partition.

This should work:

```
with c as
(
select 
    *
    , grp = row_number() over (order by datetime)
    - row_number() over (partition by switch order by datetime)
from water
)
select 
    session = row_number() over(order by min(datetime)), 
    [start time] = min(datetime), 
    [end time] = max(datetime), 
    decrease_in_level = max(waterlevel) - min(waterlevel) 
from c
where switch = 1
group by grp
order by min(datetime)
```

In the query I called you table **water** and the output, given your sample data, is:

```
| Session |               Start Time |                 End Time | decrease_in_level |
|---------|--------------------------|--------------------------|-------------------|
|       1 | August, 07 2015 09:00:00 | August, 07 2015 09:20:00 |                 2 |
|       2 | August, 07 2015 18:00:00 | August, 07 2015 18:15:00 |                 3 |
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/710590/1)

Comment: Thanks JPW, you made my life easy.

Comment: @UmairKhan Happy to help :)